# Why do I need to add Slf4j dependencies, in addition to the Lombok dependency, for logging to work?

Tags: lombok

Why am I having to add these 2 dependencies in order for my Lombok `@Slf4j` logging to work?   I am defining a `log4j.properties` file, where I enable debug on some 3rd party packages.  If I don't add these 2 slf4j dependencies, the logging doesn't work.   Shouldn't this work with just the Lombok dependency only?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my lombok dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.22</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Lombok doc](https://projectlombok.org/features/log), Lombok annotation `@Slf4j` creates

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExample.class);
```

Therefore it need slf4j dependencies. And because slf4j is just an abstraction of various actual logging library such as log4j, log4j2 and logback, bridge dependencies `slf4j-log4j12` is required.

Using slf4j abstraction is convenient for switching to another logging library.

If you just want to stick to `log4j2` logging library, you can just add [log4j2 dependencies](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html) use `@Log4j2` which creates

```
private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogExample.class)
```